# Can't click on emulator's buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to use the Nexus S API 21 emulator on android studio, It works, except that the Buttons of the smartphones don't work.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using hardware keys instead. So I think <kbd>esc</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> will work. If you want to enable the keys on the device, try `hw.mainKeys=no` in the emulators `.ini` file:

1. On OS X and Linux, you can find this `~/.android/avd/<avd_name>/config.ini`.
2. Change line `hw.mainKeys=yes` to `hw.mainKeys=no` then restart your emulator.

At one time, there was a checkbox when you were creating the emulator to select to use hardware keys or not. I have since moved on to [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/), an excellent android emulator replacement. If you can get this to work, I recommend trying that.